# How to convert an iphone app to ipad withut changing code or without making a new application?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an iphone application but i want to make it run on ipad .when i run this app. on ipad it is shown in very small screen.I have no idea of making ipad app so i cannot write code for ipad app,Can anybody tell me to make this application run on ipad without changing the code ?

Good answers will be appreciated..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode, go into the Project menu, and select "Upgrade Current Target for iPad". Choose the "Universal App" option. This will upgrade your target without changing any code at all. Open up the new iPad nib files, make sure everything looks good, and you should be good to go.

(EDIT: you'll need to manually upgrade each of your nib files, and resize and prepare them for the iPad version.)

That said, the odds are that to make things look perfect, you'll need to write some iPad code. To make this happen, create a file called `CommonMacros.h` and add:

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_2    // if iPhoneOS is 3.2 or greater then __IPHONE_3_2 will be defined

typedef enum {
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone,           // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad,             // iPad style UI
} UIUserInterfaceIdiom;

#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone

#endif // ifndef __IPHONE_3_2
```

Now, if you want to branch your code between iPhone and iPad, just add

```
#import "CommonMacros.h"
```

to the top of your `.m` file. Then, anywhere in your code, you can use this method:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad code here
} else {
    // iPhone / iPod code here
}
```

One example of where you'd do this would be if you wanted to add some extra graphical element to the iPad version, or didn't want the iPad version to have access to some iPhone feature.

Comment: cant understand your code where to write such code and how +1

Comment: pankaj, let me update my answer to be more specific. Sorry about that!

Comment: sorry for being dumb it stll wont work ,what we have to write in //ipad code here or// iphone code here

Comment: oh, you don't actually have to do anything. Follow my first instructions to convert. I just meant that if you ever do run into a situation where you need to write some code for iPad, but don't want it to affect the iPhone version, you can use that method to branch properly. Don't worry about it until you need it, though!

Comment: the ipad screen shows a 1x and 2 x icon to change screen size

Comment: once you convert your target to universal, clean it, delete it from the simulator and reload, you'll be good to go.

Comment: it does not work now the main window nib file is fully streched to work as ipad file. but other nib files still displays in small size in upper left corner of ipad

Comment: You'll need to duplicate the nib files, resized for the iPad. I'll update the answer to say that.

Comment: its very difficult to modify the xib files from iphone to ipad

Comment: yep, there's a small price to pay, but it's the only way. Does this answer the question?